# Problems with subscripting inside the parse_date_time function

Tags: r

I am encountering this issue in my code

I have the following code that works.

```
mutate(data, as.Date(parse_date_time(data$birthday, c("%d.%m.%Y", "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                                        "%Y/%m/%d", "%d-%m-%Y", 
                                                        "%m-%d-%Y"))))
```

Now, I want to apply the `parse_date_time` function to another column of my data and I write the following (now, I use brackets to subscript):

```
  mutate(data, as.Date(parse_date_time(data[, c("birthday", "subscription_date")], 
                                       c("%d.%m.%Y", "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                         "%Y/%m/%d", "%d-%m-%Y",
                                         "%m-%d-%Y"))))
```

However, I get the warning message ***All formats failed to parse. No formats found.***. Why does this happen?

thanks in advance

Comment: `parse_date_time` expects a character or numeric vector of dates as `x` argument, `data[, c("birthday", "subscription_date")]` is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` :

```
cols <- c("birthday", "subscription_date")

data[, cols] <- lapply(data[, cols], lubridate::parse_date_time, 
                 c("%d.%m.%Y", "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d", "%d-%m-%Y","%m-%d-%Y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `across` for multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data <- data %>%
       mutate(across(c(birthday, subscription_date), ~ 
              parse_date_time(.,  c("%d.%m.%Y", "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                     "%Y/%m/%d", "%d-%m-%Y",
                                     "%m-%d-%Y"))))
```